# What good are python classes?

Tags: python, class, copy, alias

It seems their only value is storing attributes.  Even then, those can't be changed or the changes get reflected across all instances!

If I have a class here:

```
# Vertex
class Vertex:
   label = str()
   ID = int()
   outEdges = list()
   inEdges = list()
```

make a new vertex object:

```
v = Vertex()
```

and add to v's outedges:

```
v.outEdges.append(1)
```

then Vertex.outEdges is no longer an empty list, but also contains 1.

So how should I use python classes?  With the copy module?  Not at all?

Comment: Why are you using class attributes here? If your data should only apply to a single instance, make it part of the instance.

Comment: Class attributes are made to be reflected across all instances.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The attributes you are declaring are class-level, and are shared by all instances of the class.  You need to use a proper initializer/constructor function if you want those values to be specific to an instance:

```
# Vertex
class Vertex:
   def __init__(self):
      self.label = str()
      self.ID = int()
      self.outEdges = list()
      self.inEdges = list()
```

You can also create methods on classes, not just attributes.

```
class Vertex:
   # def __init__(self): ...

   def allEdges(self):
      return self.outEdges + self.inEdges
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need an [instantiation method](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) if you want different instances of the class.

```
class Vertex:
    def __init__(self):
        self.label = str()
        ....
```

Answer (score 1):

> [..] the changes get reflected across all instances!

If you define attributes as you did they will behave as static attributes shared across all instances of given class.

If you want to get instances of given class which do not share attributes values you need to define it like that:

```
# Vertex
class Vertex:
    def __init__(self):
        self.label = str()
        self.ID = int()
        outEdges = list()
        inEdges = list()
```